# COUNT e GROUP BY em duas colunas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Pessoal estou enfrentando uma dúvida com uma Query em particular, já catei em todo lugar sobre o assunto mas sem sucesso. Se houver outra forma de fazer o que estou tentando, desde já agradeço pelo informação

***Então, irei ilustrar o cenário.***

**TABELA VOUCHERS**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesta tabela estou atribuindo um serial_lote já que os vouchers serão gerados em grandes quantidades, cada voucher tem um Tempo_total.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui criar uma consulta onde me retorna todos os serial_lote que foram criados nas ultimas 2 horas e as vezes que esse lote se repete.

```
SELECT serial_lote, Count(*) FROM vouchers
where (data_criacao BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 hour) AND NOW())  GROUP BY serial_lote
HAVING Count(*) > 1 
order by serial_lote DESC
```

[image: ME RETORNA ESSAS INFORMAÇÕES]

Preciso que me retorne não só o serial_lote e a quantidade de vezes que esse lote se repete, mas também o Tempo_total de cada lote.
(OS lotes só podem ser criados com o mesmo Tempo_total)

**[image: Preciso que fique assim]**

Comment: http://forum.wmonline.com.br/topic/176750-somar-horas-de-campo-tipo-time-no-mysql/ deve te ajudar

Comment: Devo ter lhe confundido, não desejo somar o tempo_total..
Desejo saber qual é o tempo de cada Lote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A função `SUM()` não funciona com dados de tipo `Time`. Por isso é preciso usar as funcões `TIME_TO_SEC` e `SEC_TO_TIME` para converter o tempo em um numero de segundos e vice-versa.

```
SELECT serial_lote, Count(*), SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `tempo_total` ) ) ) AS tempoTotal
FROM vouchers
WHERE (data_criacao BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 hour) AND NOW())  GROUP BY serial_lote
HAVING Count(*) > 1 
ORDER BY serial_lote DESC
```

EDIT: Se não quiser somar o tempo total, é só adicionar o tempo_total no `SELECT` e no `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT serial_lote, tempo_total, Count(*)
FROM vouchers
WHERE(data_criacao BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 hour) AND NOW())  
GROUP BY serial_lote, tempo_total
HAVING Count(*) > 1 
ORDER BY serial_lote DESC
```

Comment: Devo ter me expressado errado, pois o objetivo é trazer apenas o tempo do lote já que só posso criar um lote com o mesmo tempo_total. Não desejo somar, apenas quero saber que o lote 1 é de 03:00:00 e o lote 2 é de 01:00:00

Comment: @MichelTeixeira editei a minha resposta. Espero ter entendido bem

Comment: wow! obrigado @EstevaoLuis é exatamente isso que preciso, agora aprendi.. a questão do select, desculpa agora vi que foi uma coisa boba. Obrigado pela ajuda.